# Best practice to show validation errors on MVP pattern

Tags: c#, .net, mvp

I have a Presenter that is used for user registration and I need to implement validation errors on it, what I've done is I created a method for each validation error, like `UserCannotBeEmpty()`, `InvalidEmailAddress()`, `UserAlreadyExists()` and so on...

It is ok for just a few fields, but it just doesn't look good if I have a lot of fields, I would have to create a lot of methods for that...

What't the best way to do this?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's wrong with more fields - more validation? If you have 20 different fields to check, and each one requires different type of validation, **you'll have to** implement that many methods.

Sure, there are some common ways to help you here. You probably don't need `UserCannotBeEmpty` and `PasswordCannotBeEmpty` methods. Most likely you'll be fine with `CannotBeEmpty(string errorMessage)`. Refactor out stuff that's common (null checks, alphanumeric checks, datetime/number parsing and so forth - type dependant), and implement field-specific validation only when needed.

Keep in mind, domain specific validation (your business rules, eg. "shipment date cannot occur before production date") should be validated on model-side.